# for loop to list comprehension[nested for loop)

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

After a few tries I am not able to convert this for loop into a single line[list comprehension]

```
        print(cells_don[0])


        cells_v_don = list()
        for cell in cells_don:
            row = list()
            for i in range(0, len(cell)):
                row.append(cell[i].value)
            cells_v_don.append(row)
```

Output: It s just a tuple collecting data from a excel table:

(<Cell 'ede_ser'.C13>, <Cell 'ede_ser'.D13>, <Cell 'ede_ser'.E13>, <Cell 'ede_ser'.F13>, <Cell 'ede_ser'.G13>, <Cell 'ede_ser'.H13>, <Cell 'ede_ser'.I13>, <Cell 'ede_ser'.J13>, <Cell 'ede_ser'.K13>, <Cell 'ede_ser'.L13>, <Cell 'ede_ser'.M13>, <Cell 'ede_ser'.N13>, <Cell 'ede_ser'.O13>, <Cell 'ede_ser'.P13>, <Cell 'ede_ser'.Q13>, <Cell 'ede_ser'.R13>, <Cell 'ede_ser'.S13>, <Cell 'ede_ser'.T13>)

How can I convert this code into a list comprehension?

Thank you!

Comment: Will you give use an example of the `cells_don` list?

Comment: Why do you want to convert it to a comprehension? Nested loops are rarely more readable in comprehension form. Your original code is perfectly clear, readable, maintainable...

Comment: I just want to compare their performance as I am planning to import files with thousands of rows.

Comment: Fair enough. If you're processing a lot of data though, you might want to look into Pandas.

Comment: Can you directly iterate over `cell` instead of iterating the index with `for i in range(0, len(cell))` and accessing `cell[i]` in that loop's body?

Answer (score 0):

```
cells_v_don = [
    [cell[i].value for i in range(0, len(cell))]
    for cell in cells_don
]
```